# Image recognition from photos library

Tags: ios, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, google-mlkit, apple-vision

I need to create a `neural network` that will be trained using a `set of pictures`, for example 1000 pictures. Then I want this network to be able to take a as an input a `video from camera` and detect if it sees one of these pictures - but not on entire screen, but for example as a `printed picture on the wall`. And from it I would like to get some most probably seen pictures. I don't need to know their location in the input picture, just an information about which are they. So this network would **not be a classifier** - Im not interested in what this picture is of - just a name of this picture, or index in the set, or whatever. Is there some kind of neural network capable of doing something like this? It can be `TensorFlow`, `CoreML` or `MLKit` or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

try start from CreateML utility.

Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> CreateML.

Then Select "Object Detection" project.

It's used YOLO2, it's have good performance but might be not so accurate.

I recommended try it first, if this solution can't cover your's requirements then I will try help to you with YOLO5.

Comment: Also, you can try alternative way, using ARKit, [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience) ARKit picture detection sample

Comment: Thanks, but object detection detects certain types of objects, not a specific picture. The difference is that I don't need to know that I see a tree, train, car, etc, I just need to know that I see "Image 003.jpg" - exactly the same picture, and not some specific object in any visual form.

Comment: As for ARKit image detection, this is what im going to use in next step, but it only works fine for certain number of pictures. That is why I want to help it with some initial information, to limit the number of pictures it needs to search for.